# How to populate all the user fields which is inside an object inside of an array and another array in mongoose

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-populate

here is my course schema

```
const CourseSchema = new Schema(
  {
    courseName: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
      lowercase: true,
    },
    comments: [
      [
        {
          user: {
            type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: "Users",
            required: true,
          },
          comment: {
            type: String,
            required: true,
          },
          createdAt: {
            type: Date,
            required: true,
          },
        },
      ],
    ],
  },
  {
    timestamps: true,
  }
);
const Course = mongoose.model("Course", CourseSchema);
```

I want to populate the user field. I've tried many stack overflow solutions but none of them works for me.

I populated the model like this but, doing so it only populates the first index the of every model.
courses = await Course.findOne({}).populate({
path: "comments.0.0.user",
});

Answer (score 0):

You can populate another level deeper, here's what you need to do:

```
 db.Course.findOne({}).populate({"path":"comments",populate:[{
    path:"user",
     model:"Users"
    }]})
```

Another way of nested populating data:

```
db.Course.findOne({}).populate("comments.user")
```